# How to use tabs to display information of specific user instead of just the first

Tags: html, css, angular

I am getting multiple users from an API call and all are being generated with the same html and css. When I navigate the tabs of each user only the first user changes instead of the specific user. I have tried interpolating the id but comes to no effect. Here is the code.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" class="container emp-profile">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#about" role="tab" aria-controls="about" aria-selected="true">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="address-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#address" role="tab" aria-controls="address" aria-selected="false">Address</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="company-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#company" role="tab" aria-controls="company" aria-selected="false">Company</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about-tab">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not provide static id to html elements when using an *ngFor.** You will get several html elements with the same id, so your `<a>` tags won't know where to go exactly and will target the first they encounter. That's why only your first user changes.

You can specify a dynamic id using Angular :

```
<div [id]="'my-tab-' + user.name"></div> // id === 'my-tab-user1'
```